# Writing an interpreter in C++

Tags: c++, regex, qt, interpreter

I'm working on a C++ project which should do following operations:

---

1. Open a .txt file which contains list of strings
   (for example String1: "**Hi,name_1_is,;Ondrej,age24;year,,88;**") with optional values determined by empty commas "**,,**".
2. After this check each string using regular expressions for valid input
   (like "**Hi**" shouldn't be a number or "***1***" must be a number and everything with "**,,**" is optional and can be skipped or user can enter this value as well).
3. Then evaluate the result and save it to variable or new .txt generated file.
4. This result shows if whole string is correct with an "**ok**" message attached to it or it will attach "**not ok**" message right to the parameter with wrong input.

---

- I have already finished the part with opening a .txt file, checking the whole string and saving the right strings to the new file (using **Qt** and **Visual Studio 2010 Express**).
- I need to do the part where each parameter will be checked but somehow I don't know how exactly, as I should **not** build **Parser** but the whole programm **must be** build like **Interpreter**.

Actually I'm stucked at this point because I have no idea how to start to build this like an Interpreter.

All my attempts resulted always with structure similar to Parser
(that means: I used split string, then checked each token or char using regex, then built the string together again, ect.)

Could you provide me with some usefull links or tips of how to achieve that or at least where to start at all please?

Comment: I was under the impression that parsing was necessary for interpreting. Can you describe (or transcribe, if this is for some assignment) what exactly is not allowed in a "standalone" interpreter?

Comment: I'll try to be more specific at this point.

Comment: You are already doing parsing (breaking into tokens and analyzing them). can you be more clear regarding your problem?

Comment: At the beginning I had an .xml file with these strings written in between <tag>String1</tag><tag>String2</tag>,ect. I made a programm which went through all these tags, grabbed all strings between them, distinguished between comments and real strings like "Hi,name,is;..." and saved these real strings into new .txt file. Basically I parsed the .xml file. Now I should control these saved strings with above mentioned methods. The program should be like this at the end: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpreter_pattern. Basically i need to build syntax to be able to intepret and check these strings

Comment: I hope I could provide more description. Like I said. I'm unsure how to make such an Interpreter mentioned in the url.

Comment: What I achieved was to split strings, validate each splitted token with regex pattern and then put them together again and save them. Now I have to do it without splitting every single string because I have few thousand strings to check and it should run as fast as possible. That's why I should build something like interpreter which check the syntax only without necessary split. I hope I was even more specific now. Please let me know if it wasn't enough.

Comment: @Ondrej, what you are asking makes absolutely no sense. You can't do "syntax checking" without first parsing the string.

Comment: I see, so I have to parse a string first to be able to check the tokens at all and then? Thanks for the quick response by the way...

Comment: As you can see I'm new to this stuff, that's why I'm asking and trying to understand how it works. I appreciate all your help you can provide me :)